# Problems with reading objects from another file with php

Tags: php, json

I have some file called **main.config** which has:

```
{"name":"wtf","image":"main.PNG","desc":"This is about this that and that.","tags":{"php","js","html"}}
```

Now in php I am reading this file and getting its content like this:

```
$string = "";
$handle = fopen("main.config", "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $string .= fgets($handle);
}
fclose($handle);
```

And now I have been trying to decode this but it always return either `null` or string with additional `""` around.

```
"{"name":"wtf","image":"main.PNG","desc":"This is about this that and that.","tags":{"php","js","html"}}"
```

This is everything I tried:

```
json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string), true );
json_decode(preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$string), true);
json_decode(preg_replace('/\x{FEFF}/u', '', $string), true);
json_decode(str_replace('&quot;', '"', $string));
utf8_encode($string); 
stripslashes($string);
trim($string);
html_entity_decode($string);
json_decode(print_r($string, true), true);
```

But nothing seems to work, is it because I used some different file type or what could it be?

Comment: You could probably use something like: `$configJson= json_decode(file_get_contents('main.config', true);`

Comment: Your original string doesn't appear to be valid JSON

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ Just fix your json string to proper format the tags array is wrong. Then use json_decode(file_get_contents('main.config', true);  array ex: "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]

Comment: `"tags":{"php","js","html"}` I don't think this is valid JSON, it should be `"tags":["php","js","html"]`

Comment: @Danny yeah u are right, now its working even without file_get_contents. Is there a reason to use file_get_contents instead of my way?

Comment: @StupidKid Easier, less code. You can leave it the way you are doing it if you want but for small things like that you will probably see file_get_contents a lot more often in other peoples code.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Add it as answer if you want me to accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just an invalid json formatted string.

Change to:

```
{"name":"wtf","image":"main.PNG","desc":"This is about this that and that.","tags":["php","js","html"]}
```

You can also read the content with less code using:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('main.config', true);
```

If you want to validate json format you can use this site also: [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)